# Compose uiState hoist went wrong

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I face a problem about compost uiState hoisting, when hoisting uiState field will be unpredictable

```
@Composable
internal fun TestScreen(
    viewModel: TestViewModel
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    TestScreen(
        uiState: TestUiState,
    )

}

@Composable
internal fun TestScreen(
    uiState: TestUiState,
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    listState.OnBottomReached {
        if (uiState.isFirstFetching) return@OnBottomReached
        loadMore()
    }
}
```

uiState.isFirstFetching will always be initial value, listState.OnBottomReached won't get newest uiState value if uiState change

but If I just use one screen, it will correct

```
@Composable
internal fun TestScreen(
    viewModel: TestViewModel
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    listState.OnBottomReached {
         if (uiState.isFirstFetching) return@OnBottomReached
         loadMore()
    }

}
```

This is my onBottomReach code

```
@Composable
fun LazyListState.OnBottomReached(
    buffer: Int = 0,
    onLoadMore: (() -> Unit)
) {

    require(buffer >= 0) { "buffer cannot be negative, but was $buffer" }

    val lazyListState = this

    LaunchedEffect(lazyListState) {
        snapshotFlow { lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo }
            .collect { visibleItems ->
                val lastVisibleItemIndex = visibleItems.lastOrNull()?.index ?: -1
                val shouldLoadMore = lastVisibleItemIndex == lazyListState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 - buffer
                if (shouldLoadMore) {
                    onLoadMore()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

My confusion is why the two methods seem the same, but hoisting the uiState one level results in a difference.

Answer (score 0):

`LaunchedEffect` is not recomposed unless one of the keys changes, so it holds a reference to the `uiState` with which it was created. In order to indicate that you want the lambda to use the latest value of `uiState`, you have to wrap it inside a `rememberUpdatedState`:

```
@Composable
internal fun TestScreen(
    uiState: TestUiState,
) {
    val currentUiState by rememberUpdatedState(uiState)

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    listState.OnBottomReached {
        if (currentUiState.isFirstFetching) return@OnBottomReached
        loadMore()
    }
}
```

See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#rememberupdatedstate

As to why it works when all the code is inside just one screen, I'd say it's because when you do `val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()` you're actually reading from a `State` object and forcing `LaunchedEffect` to use the latest value (just as `rememberUpdatedState` does).